# Swap to Development Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hy,
I Keep getting this error after I started using IMailservice

> Development Mode
> Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.
> The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

My application has not been published yet.
My environment vairable in launchSettings.json is set to Development,
I've also set it from commandline using `>setx`,
I've also checked project>properties>debug.
My IMailService

```
    {
        Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string content);
    }
    public class SendGridMailService : IMailService
    {
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string content)
        {
            var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGrid"];
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("somemail@gmail.com", "MyApplication");
            var to = new EmailAddress(toEmail);
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, content, content);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Register action

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Registers(Registration registration)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = registration.Email,
                    Email = registration.Email
                };
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registration.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Accounts", new { userId = user.Id, token }, Request.Scheme);
                    await mailService.SendEmailAsync(registration.Email, "Account Confirmation", confirmationLink);
                    ViewBag.ErrorTitle = "Registration Successful";
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Before you can login, Please Confirm your email. Thank you";
                     return RedirectToPage("/Error");
                }
                foreach(var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
            return View(registration);
        }
```

I've also changed my startupclass to

```
if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The launchSettings.json file is used only when you run/debug your project in Visual Studio or with dotnet cli, so in that case you don't need to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable anywhere else.

Once your application is deployed to IIS the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT could be set on couple different ways including one you mentioned - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows

For me it looks like a typo when you were run a setx command and you have set an incorrect value. Make sure the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is correct on a system level.